# Autostart a Tmuxinator project on bootup under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, tmux, autostart, tmuxinator

I have configured a **Tmuxinator project** I want to have running on my server at all times. What bugs me is that I did not manage to get it to **start automatically** after (unexpected) reboots. Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Editing **/etc/rc.local** so that it now contains:

   ```
   mux start project &
   exit 0
   ```
2. (Following [this guide](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html)) creating a script that contains

   ```
   case "$1" in
       start)
       echo "Starting muxproject"
       mux start project
       ;;
   ```

   and configuring it with

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d NameOfYourScript defaults
   ```
3. (From the same guide:) Editing **etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart** and adding the line

   ```
   @mux start project
   ```

   to it.

None of the above has worked. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you please share your solution? I'm trying to start tmuxinator at boot, but no success so far.

Answer (score 4):

cron has a nice @reboot line, which you can use if the machine has rebooted. An entry in your user's crontab like:

> @reboot /usr/local/bin/mux start project

should work.

Comment: Sounds good, thx. In the meantime I did find another solution myself. It is very closely coupled to the procedure explained here -> http://reinhard-seiler.blogspot.de/2013/05/tutorial-how-to-automatically-start.html . But still, I would like to try and validate your solution soon.

Comment: @moejoe Can you please share your solution? I'm trying to start tmuxinator at boot, but no success so far.

Comment: Autostart tmux session -> http://reinhard-seiler.blogspot.com/2013/05/tutorial-how-to-automatically-start.html?showComment=1402712084045#c2223168502529568404

make tmuxinator startup init.d script booting with sudo update-rc.d tmuxinator.sh defaults